# VBA pasteFormats activating the destination worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I have a problem with pasting columns

```
    Set SourceWBsht = Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Source")
    Set DestinationWBsht= Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Destination")
    SourceWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").EntireColumn.Copy
    DestinationWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").EntireColumn.PasteSpecial  _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

    SourceWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").EntireRow.Copy
    DestinationWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").EntireRow.PasteSpecial _
    Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

The problem is VBA activating the destination sheet automatically, Somehow, I am trying to avoid it. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: in my Excel 2103 your code doesn't activate "Destination" worksheet. May be some statement before or after your shown code is doing that: step through your code and chek for it

Comment: Yes, using the debugging tool. no problems with it.
It activate other worksheets only in the full code.

Comment: I don't get any "destination" sheet activation in either way. Maybe "destination" sheet is the _active_ one when you start the macro

Comment: No, a third sheet is the home sheet.

Comment: then, unless your Excel version acts that way, it's your preceeding or subsequent code making that sheet activation

Comment: Most probably, Yes. I will try to comment the whole code and uncomment it line by line.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelKhalek My answer didn't help you?

Comment: Hi Marius, I canceled this part from the code. Thank you for your reply and help.

Comment: Anything special should I do to help?
I am still new to the website.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
 DestinationWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").value = SourceWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").value
```

Edit 1: After Comment

```
SourceWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").Copy
DestinationWBsht.Range("A1:Z40").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: I am trying to paste the column formats and colors, not values.