# Excel 2013 random sheet activation post macro run

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue where by, since updating my Office suite to 2013, the code that I've been running in prior versions worked without issue.  However, now in 2013, the (same) macro always activates the last sheet in the book post running.  The structure of the book is Control sheet (where buttons and macros are called from), other sheet, ..., final sheet.  Upon clicking any of the buttons on the Control sheet, it always results in me being active on the final sheet.  This is fully unique to Excel 2013.

Within all of these scrips, there is a protection model (for each sheet in wb.sheets, protect / unprotect) so perhaps in this looping it is somehow glitching at the last sheet?

The syntax for that code is:

```
Public Sub sbProtection(ByVal sType As String)

Dim wb As Workbook

Dim ws As Worksheet

    'Setup
Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    'Toggle
If UCase(sType) = "PROTECT" Then

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ws.Protect sPassword
    Next ws

ElseIf UCase(sType) = "UNPROTECT" Then

    For Each ws In wb.Sheets
        ws.Unprotect sPassword
    Next ws

End If

    'Cleanup
Set wb = Nothing
Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Any idea what is happening?

Comment: There is nothing in this code which will activate a sheet. What is the code which is calling this sub routine i.e how this sub routine is being called?

Comment: Also do you maybe have a worksheet change or some similar event that may fire?  Try stepping through your macro with `F8` and see if you can tell when/where it activates that "random sheet".

Comment: I think this is a problem in Excel 2013 and I didn't found a solution for it. Now I save the active sheet to a worksheet variable before running my code and after finish reactivate this worksheet. this question [VBA pasteFormats activating the destination worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42620502/4039286) is about similar problem.

Comment: I run your code in Excel 2013 called by a button in "first" sheet with no issue: the active sheet stays the "first" one after `sbProtection` run. Maybe you have some workbook event handler that runs at workbook opening or what?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments... this is being called at the beginning and end of a 'compile data' subroutine... so sbCompile call sbProtection("UNPROTECT") '--- do stuff ---' then sbProtection("PROTECT") End Sub.  There is no other event handling and I repeat this is only unique to Excel 2013. Interestingly enough, by stepping through the code, the error is not present.  And by simply commenting out those sbProtection calls, the error is not present via allowing the code to run via calling from a button.